# Angular extract array from expected object response

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, wordpress

I am working with wordpress' rest api and I am extracting a list of posts which allow the user to see a single post. Now I want to include the comments as well but I cannot wrap my head around this. I am using a factory for the calls:

```
.factory('Articles', function ($http) {
    var articles = [];
       storageKey = "articles";

    function _getCache() {
        var cache = localStorage.getItem(storageKey );
        if (cache)
            articles = angular.fromJson(cache);
    }


    return {
        all: function () {
            return $http.get("http://www.examplesite.com/tna_wp/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=test").then(function (response) {
                articles = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
                return articles;
            });
        },

        get: function (articleId) {
            if (!articles.length) 
                _getCache();
            for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
                if (parseInt(articles[i].ID) === parseInt(articleId)) {
                    return articles[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
})
```

My controller:

```
.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, _, Articles) {
  $scope.articles = [];
  Articles.all().then(function (response){
      $scope.articles = response;
      window.localStorage.setItem("articles", JSON.stringify(response));
  }, 

  function (err) {
     if(window.localStorage.getItem("articles") !== undefined) {
        $scope.articles = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("articles"));
      }
    }
  );
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    Articles.all().then(function (articles){
      var loadedIds = _.pluck($scope.articles, 'id');
      var newItems = _.reject(articles, function (item){ 
         return _.contains(loadedIds, item.id); 
    });
      $scope.articles = newItems.concat($scope.articles);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    });
  };

})






//THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING AND FAILING
.controller('ExampleInnerCtrl', function ($http, $scope, $stateParams, $cordovaSocialSharing, $ionicModal, Articles) {
  $scope.article = Articles.get($stateParams.articleId);
   var url = Articles.get($stateParams.articleId);


  $scope.comments = [];

  $http.get("http://www.example.com/tna_wp/wp-json/posts/" +url+ "/comments").then(function (response, commentId) {
      $scope.comments = response.data;

      console.log(response.data);
      return $scope.comments;
  });

  $scope.comment = $stateParams.commentId;




  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('gauteng-comments.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal
  })  

  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show()
  }

  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });

  $scope.sharePost = function(link){
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share('I just read this article on The New engage: ', null, null, "http://example.com" + link);
  };

})
```

now in the controller if I include the post id manually I can get the comments for that post, however I cannot seem to store that post ID in a variable to use

--------EDIT

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: "NavCtrl"
  })

    .state('app.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.provinces', {
      url: "/provinces",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/provinces.html"
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.example', {
      url: "/provinces/example",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/example.html",
        controller: "ExampleCtrl"
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.exampleSingle', {
      url: "/provinces/example/:articleId",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/exampleSingle.html",
        controller: "ExampleInnerCtrl"
        }
      }
    })

;

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/home");
});
```

Comment: Can you please add your ui-router configuration to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was my stupidity... I just stored the variable as: `var url = $scope.article.ID;`